# Segmentation Fault- C programming

Tags: c, arrays, string, segmentation-fault, coredump

This program is supposed to read in 10 strings and print the ones that end in "ed" however even though it compiles,I keep getting a segmentation fault after I enter my first string. I've tried everything and I just cant figure out why. Heres my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    //Declaration of array of strings
    char *strings[10];
    int i = 0;
    int len = 0;

    //Prompts user to enter 10 strings

    printf("Enter 10 strings: \n");

    //Loop to read in 10 strings

    for( i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        fgets(strings[i], 100, stdin);
    }

    //Loop to traverse array of strings and print those ending with 'ed'

    printf("The strings that end with ed are:\n");

    for( i=0; i < 10; i++)
    {   

        len=strlen(strings[i]);

        len=len-1;

        if(*strings[len] =='e' && *strings[len-1] =='d')
        {
            printf("%s", strings[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}//End of function main
```

Comment: Your program passes an uninitialized pointer to `fgets()`.

Comment: Change `char *strings[10]` to `char strings[10][100]`

Comment: Where is `fgets` supposed to write to? You haven't allocated anything.

Comment: `strings[i]` has not been initialized before your loop.

Comment: char *strings[10] does not declare an array of strings. It simply declares an array of pointers to char *, and you do not initialize these pointers to valid memory. So when you try to access strings[0], you seg fault!

Comment: @jxh The "find"ing part is entirely wrong.

Comment: and That the new line is included at the end of the line is not taken into consideration. It is also necessary to check that a valid character is 2 or more characters.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I managed to fix it by doing what @RikayanBandyopadhyay said but now it wont print anything. Also realised I had the endings in reverse.

Comment: @user3552985 You got the "find"ing part wrong, as I said. See [Vlad from Moscow's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24686359/1519469).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not allocated memory for `string` elements. Allocate memory for it.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    strings[i] = malloc(100);
```

At the end do not forget to free the allocated memory using `free`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    free(string[i]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Memory is not allocated for string variable `string`. You only declared pointer to 10 strings

```
char *strings[10];
```

There is no memory for the string array or variable hence you have to  allocate it

```
 for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
      string[i]=malloc((max_length_of_string));
  }
```

You can take `max_length_of_string` to be 100.

Answer (score 1):

Define the array the following way

```
char strings[10][100];
```

Also this code snippet is incorrect

```
for( i=0; i < 10; i++)
{   

    len=strlen(strings[i]);

    len=len-1;

    if(*strings[len] =='e' && *strings[len-1] =='d')
    {
        printf("%s", strings[i]);
    }
}
```

Try the following

```
for( i=0; i < 10; i++)
{   

    len=strlen(strings[i]);

    if ( len && strings[i][len - 1] == '\n' ) --len;

    if ( len > 1 && strings[i][len - 1] =='d' && strings[i][len-2] =='e')
    {
        printf("%s", strings[i]);
    }
}
```

Here is an example of how the program could look

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    //Declaration of array of strings
    const size_t N = 10;
    const size_t M = 100;
    char strings[N][M];
    size_t i;
    size_t len;

    //Prompts user to enter 10 strings

    printf( "Enter %u strings: \n", N );

    //Loop to read in 10 strings

    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        fgets( strings[i], M, stdin );
    }

    //Loop to traverse array of strings and print those ending with 'ed'

    printf( "The strings that end with ed are:\n" );

    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {   
        len = strlen( strings[i] );

        if ( len && strings[i][len - 1] == '\n' ) --len;

        if ( len > 1 && strings[i][len - 1] =='d' && strings[i][len - 2] =='e' )
        {
            printf( "%s", strings[i] );
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If to input

```
apple
room
horse
finished
close
chicken
city
done
success
opened
```

then the output will be

```
finished
opened
```

Comment: @BLUEPIXY  Are you sure?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Yes, because `len` is decremented from 2 to 1, so `len - 2` produces a negative index.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Oh, I made a mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Some of these issues might be beyond the scope of your project.

- You do not allocate any memory for your strings.
- You pass an uninitialized pointer to `fgets()`.
- You do not adequately handle the problem of the input string being very long (more than 99 characters).
- You do not adequately handle the problem of the input string being very short (fewer than 2 characters).
- You do not adequately handle the problem of the input having fewer than the expected number or strings.
- You do not adequately deal with the issue of `fgets()` including the newline of the input in the end of the resulting string.
- You improperly use `strings[len]` when you mean `strings[i][len]`.
- You are checking for `"de"` instead of `"ed"` as intended.

Below is one possible solution to resolve these problems:

```
int
main (void)
{
    char *strings[10] = {}, *x;
    int i;
    size_t len;

    puts("Enter 10 strings:");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) getline(&strings[i], &len, stdin);
    puts("The strings that end with ed are:");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        if ((x = strings[i])) {
            len = strlen(x);
            if (x[len-1] == '\n') x[--len] = '\0';
            if (len > 1 && strcmp(x + len - 2, "ed") == 0) puts(x);
            free(x);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```